# Windows Forms ComboBox Initialization is very slow (Win32 API CreateWindowEx)

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

Windows Forms Comboboxes seem to be very slow to initialize, compared with other forms of controls.

I'm getting the following numbers:

- Button: 2ms
- Empty ComboBox: 53ms
- ComboBox with 100 items: 264ms

I debug-stepped into the Windows Forms source to determine what takes so long. Almost all of the time is spent in CreateWindowExW, via the following call stack:

```
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.CreateHandle(System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams cp) Line 473  
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateHandle() Line 4969  
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.CreateHandle() Line 2451 
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(bool fIgnoreVisible) Line 5036  
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl() Line 4995 
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection.Add(System.Windows.Forms.Control value) Line 126    
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.ControlCollection.Add(System.Windows.Forms.Control value) Line 60
```

How can I speed up ComboBox creation?

The test code is below.

```
public class Timer : IDisposable
{
    private readonly string _taskName;
    private readonly Stopwatch _stopwatch;

    public Timer(string taskName)
    {
        _taskName = taskName;
        _stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _stopwatch.Stop();
        Debug.WriteLine($"{_taskName} took {_stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
    }
}
internal static void Run()
{
    // If you remove the following line, everything is MUCH faster:
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    using (var f = new Form())
    {
        f.Show();

        // warmup
        f.Controls.Add(new Label());
        f.Controls.Add(new ComboBox());
        f.Controls.Add(new Button());

        
        using (new Timer("adding combobox to form"))
        {
            var cb = new ComboBox();
            f.Controls.Add(cb);
        }

        
        using (new Timer("adding combobox with many items to form"))
        {
            var cb = new ComboBox();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                cb.Items.Add(i.ToString());
            f.Controls.Add(cb);
        }

        using (new Timer("adding a button to form"))
        {   
            var button  = new Button() { Text = "Testing" };
            f.Controls.Add(button);
        }
    }

}
```

### Results of additional experiments suggested by commenters

- **What if you first add the controls, and then show the form?** This is much faster overall (100ms for everything). However, this is not applicable to my real application, where I need to add the controls after the form has already been shown.
- **What if you use BeginUpdate and EndUpdate to populate the combobox?** This does not change the timings by much. The adding is very fast, regardless of whether BeginUpdate is used. What's slow is the CreateWindowEx call.
- **What if you use SuspendLayout and ResumeLayout? And add the controls in one go using Controls.AddRange?** This doesn't change the timing either.
- **Application.EnableVisualStyles is the culprit:** With this, combobox initialization gets 10x slower. I have added EnableVisualStyles to the test code above.

Comment: You're testing this stuff backwards. You need to create the Form's instance, then add Controls, then show the Form (which you cannot do here, since you're disposing of it immediately). You also need to call `.SuspendLayout()` / `.ResumeLayout(false)`. Controls as the ComboBox / LIstBox / ListView etc.,, need to call `.BeginUpdate()` before inserting multiple items, and `.EndUpdate()` to complete the operation. When you do everything in the correct order and using the correct methods, you could end up measuring `0 `ms (btw, the measures you're showing are too high in any case)

Comment: Ok, so ComboBox takes more time to add than a TextBox. What does that tell us? That a Win32 combobox (which is more complex than a listbox) takes more time to add than a listbox? What's the problem? "Slow" is very relative concept. The 100 loop takes 8 ms on my i5-13600K PC the rest is 0 or 1ms.

Comment: @SimonMourier What if you follow the procedure described above? Most of all, show the Form as the last operation. How much does the loop take, also adding `.BeginUpdate()` / `.EndUpdate()`?

Comment: @jimi - I think op's point was about combobox being slower to create than other controls. I think it's true, but I don't see the problem.

Comment: @SimonMourier Yes, but, here, what is measured, is the wrong thing to measure. The OP's measuring how much time it takes to perform the layout of those Controls. The ComboBox performs updates for each element added if that's not blocked. When you do block the updates, is it the slowest, considering the loop? -- I can't run this code right now, it appears you can, might as well test it. I'm pretty sure the results would change quite a bit (better measure ticks than milliseconds then, IMO)

Comment: @Jimi I ran the experiment you suggested - add the controls, then show the form. This is much faster. However, this doesn't help me in the real application where I need to add controls after the form has already been sown.

Comment: @Jimi I also tried using BeginUpdate and EndUpdate. It did not change anything (the slowness isn't in the adding of the items, but in the adding of the control to the form and the CreateWindowEx call this triggers). Finally, I tested SuspendLayout and ResumeLayout - no luck either.

Comment: Finally, I discovered one thing: When calling Application.EnableVisualStyles before creating the comboboxes, it gets 10x slower. Without EnableVisualStyles, things are much faster. I have added Application.EnableVisualStyles to the test code above.

Comment: Most probably you have something in the test application that slows things down. Not `.EnableVisualStyles`. You should specify the .NET version you're targeting and some specs on the test machine -- Since you need to add Controls to an already shown Form, make another test: suspend the layout of the Form, build all Controls, set their properties, add items, whatever. In the end, call `f.Controls.AddRange([ the, single, controls ]);`. Resume the layout and measure it <- If you cannot use that syntax, you're on an old version of .NET / C#

Comment: @Jimi Thanks. No luck either, now the slowness is in Controls.AddRange (hundreds of ms). ResumeLayout runs in 0ms, so basically BeginLayout / ResumeLayout has  no effect.

Comment: @Jimi I can pinpoint it down to .EnableVisualStyles. With EnableVisualStyles, timing is as reported above (hundreds of ms). Without it, it's <50ms. This is measured on the test code above and in a fresh project.

Comment: As mentioned, post some details on the .NET version, the test machine and the context in which this code is run -- Tested now this all procedure. In my machine, the whole thing takes 29ms / 32ms with Visual Styles enabled and 24ms / 29ms without (20 runs - .NET 8 Project)

Comment: This is .NET 6, ran in debug mode, without debugger attached, from Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 11, with a Ryzen 5900HX CPU. The problem does not happen on every run, but at least 70% of the time.

Comment: I've repeated the test, release mode, Visual Styles enabled, `SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false)` (standard configuration). The times are those previously described (slightly less, it's release mode), 100 runs, 6 Controls added. A couple of times it went over 50ms, most of the time less than 30ms. My test machine is far from a beast